# Way to get rid of elastic bounce back effect on SAFARI browser allowing scroll on selected elements on ipad/iphone?

Tags: javascript, jquery, safari, mobile-safari

I've tried almost all possible ways to block the bounce back effect on SAFARI on ipad and iphone still allowing scrolling on selected elements but with no luck.
I have also tried to use iScroll and other libraries but I have not found yet a good approach to this problem.

With this code snippet I can block the bounce back effect but then I am not able to scroll the page.

Do you know any solution to allow scrolling on selected elements?

```
$(document).bind(
      'touchmove',
          function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
          }
        );
```